# NVD3 fixing up the width of the chart to fill up the svg element

Tags: css, nvd3.js

I'm still exploring NVD3 so bear with me.

I am trying to put four bar charts next to each other, each with 25% width, that's what I currently get:
[image]

From that HTML code:

```
<div class="inline">
    <div id="status" class="d3chart d3chart-sm wd-25"><svg></svg></div>
    <div id="shop" class="d3chart d3chart-sm wd-25"><svg></svg></div>
    <div id="week" class="d3chart d3chart-sm wd-25"><svg></svg></div>
    <div id="age" class="d3chart d3chart-sm wd-25"><svg></svg></div>
</div>
```

The `<svg>` tags are at 25% width and actually fill up the blank area to the left of each chart but the chart itself which gets rendered after the page runs doesn't fill up this area:
[image]

Here's a fiddle of the whole thing: http://jsfiddle.net/re3yod01/1/

How can I get these charts to fill up the svg elements that contain them?

Comment: Have you tried commenting out `.margin({top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 175})` ?

Comment: @shabeer90 yeah that's where the problem was it seems, that's a bit odd because i couldn't see any css margins in when checking the elements through chrome's dev tools

Comment: If my comment helped solve it, feel free to accept the answer and close this question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try commenting out the margins on the chart :

`.margin({top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 175})`

Hope it helps